# Having the class handle pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I am changing some code to spin up VMs in ec2 instead of openstack.  Main starts a thread per VM, and then various modules perform tasks on these VM.  Each thread controls it's own VM.  So, instead of either having to add parameters to all of the downstream modules to look up information, or having to change all of the code to unpickle the class instance that created the vm, I am hoping that I can have the class itself decide whether to start a new VM or return the existing pickle. That way the majority of the code wont need to be altered.

This is the general idea, and closest I have gotten to getting it to work:

```
import os
import sys
import pickle
if sys.version_info >= (2, 7):
    from threading import current_thread
else:
    from threading import currentThread as current_thread



class testA:
    def __init__(self, var="Foo"):
        self.class_pickle_file = "%s.p" % current_thread().ident
        if os.path.isfile(self.class_pickle_file):
            self.load_self()
        else:
            self.var = var
            pickle.dump(self, open(self.class_pickle_file, "wb"))
    def test_method(self):
        print self.var
    def load_self(self):
        return pickle.load(open(self.class_pickle_file, "rb"))




x = testA("Bar")
y = testA()
y.test_method()
```

But that results in: `NameError: global name 'var' is not defined`

But, If I do `y = pickle.load(open("140355004004096.p", "rb"))` it works just fine.  So the data IS getting in there by storing `self` inside the class, it's a problem of getting the class to return the pickle instead of itself...

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you create a file named by the current thread's ident, then you instantiate another TestA object using the same thread (!!same ident!!), so it checks for a pickle file (and finds it, that's bad), then self.var never gets set.

In test_method, you check for a variable that was never set.

Run each item in its own thread to get different idents, or ensure you set self.var no matter what.

Comment: Yes, the goal is for it to find it and load that version of that class from the pickle that is returned, which has self.var defined (it does when I load it from outside of the class, but not when I load it from inside of the class)

Comment: Yes - but I think where I'm miscommunicating is that it is your test method that's not working out.  You are storing things based on the id of the thread, but that isn't accomplishing what you may hope for it to accomplish.  I think you want a unique pickle for each instance of the class, but instead, you are saving any class created in that thread to the same pickle file.